# (Leaf.xNet) how to parse cookies as a variable with cookie name

Tags: c#, cookies, substring, httprequest

I'm using leaf.xNet Library for HTTP requests, and I wanna know how to parse Cookies with the Cookie name, using `SubString` if possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation https://github.com/csharp-leaf/Leaf.xNet

```cs
string response = request.Get("https://twitter.com/login").ToString();
var cookies = request.Cookies.GetCookies("https://twitter.com");
foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies) {
    // concat your string or do what you want
    Console.WriteLine($"{cookie.Name}: {cookie.Value}");
}
```